# Why can I still decrypt parts of my data after flipping a bit in the ciphertext?

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am using in my application AES algorithm to encrypt my data. My key is of 256 bit. The encrypted token formed is of this sort:

```
pRplOI4vTs41FICGeQ5mlWUoq5F3bcviHcTZ2hN
```

Now if I change one bit of the token alphabet from upper case to lower case say some thing like this:

```
prplOI4vTs41FICGeQ5mlWUoq5F3bcviHcTZ2hN
```

Some part of the token is getting decrypted along with junk value. My concern is why even some part of the data is getting visible when as such one bit is changed.My code for encryption is as follows:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        Key secretKeySpecification = secretKeyData.getKey();
        cipher.init(
                Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,
                secretKeySpecification,
                new IvParameterSpec(secretKeyData.getIV().getBytes("UTF-8")));
        byte[] bytesdata = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
     String encodedData = new BASE64Encoder().encode(bytesdata)
```

My code for decryption is:

```
                Key secretKeySpecification = decryptionKeyDetails.getKey();
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpecification,
                new IvParameterSpec(decryptionKeyDetails.getIV()
                        .getBytes("UTF-8")));
        byte[] bytesdata;

        byte[] tempStr = new BASE64Decoder()
                .decodeBuffer(splitedData[0]);
        bytesdata = cipher.doFinal(tempStr);
        return new String(bytesdata);
```

Comment: [cypto SE:Malleability attacks against encryption without authentication](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3654/malleability-attacks-against-encryption-without-authentication) explains, why, after you change a single byte in the first block, the first block decrypts as garbage but the second block decrypts as mostly intact except for a single byte in the same position that was changed in the first block.

Comment: use authenticated encryption

Comment: @CodeslnChaos are you telling to use some hashing like MD5 to do it or their is some other better approach for the same, please help I am very new to this?

Comment: Authentication in this context would mean a separate MAC such as HMAC, or an authenticated encryption mode such as GCM. And please don't use `sun.misc.*` classes.

Comment: Wow, comments from Oleg, Codes and ntoskrnl, you must have lucky genes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciphertext [modes of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) have specific forms of [error propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Error_propagation). There is such as thing as Bi-IGE (Bi-directional Infinite Garble Extension, that does change the whole plaintext if any error is introduced. However, it requires more than one pass, and it still won't protect you from getting random data if a bit was changed.

In the end, listen to Oleg and Codes (and Wikipedia and even me) and add an authentication tag to your ciphertext. Validate the authentication tag (e.g. HMAC) *before* decryption. Don't forget to include other data in your protocol such as the IV, or you may have a plaintext for which the first block has been changed.

Comment: validity of data is more important than its visibility, in that case which would be a better approach the above or just a signature with SHA 512 would be fare enough?

Comment: Don't use Bi-IGE. Otherwise it is a choice that depends mostly on the protocol. I would myself prefer a HMAC, as I would not want to mix symmetric and asymmetric for the same message by adding a signature.

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer? Don't forget to accept answers (in general)!